# What mental imagery does 如麻 invoke?

Tags: word

People use the idiom 杀人如麻 all the time but hemp is no longer a familiar scene to most people, and I doubt anyone ever saw a hemp in his whole life. Exactly what mental imagery is 麻 supposed to invoke?

Comment: bkrs：[kill people like flies; commit innumerable murders; decimate the population] 形容杀人极多
朝避猛虎, 夕避长蛇。 磨牙吮血, 杀人如麻。 --唐·李白《蜀道难》
这是一个杀人如麻的惯匪，【释义】如麻：象乱麻一样数不清。杀死的人多得象乱麻。形容杀的人多得数不清。
【近义】嗜血成性、斩尽杀绝
【反义】救死扶伤
**如麻** ：
1) 形容杂乱。e。g。心乱如麻
2) 形容密集、多。e。g。屋漏如麻  
雨脚如麻 also note generic name for hemp, flax etc; hemp or flax fiber for textile materials; sesame; CL:缕[lu:3]; (of materials) rough or coarse; pocked; pitted; to have pins and needles or tingling; to feel numb; surname Ma 小马词典 has 138 compounds using 麻

Comment: Thanks, but no dictionary definition can help. My guess is it depicts the chaotic scene of hemp field when hemp plants were mowed down by scythe.

Comment: 杀人如麻 is one of many 成语 starting with 杀人如, some others involving more familiar plants, see e.g. https://zuciwang.com/zhuanti/%E4%BB%80%E4%B9%88%E4%BA%BA%E5%A6%82%E4%BB%80%E4%B9%88%E7%9A%84%E6%88%90%E8%AF%AD.html 【杀人如藨】杀人像割草一样。形容把杀人不当一回事。 【杀人如草】形容杀人多，极轻视人命。 【杀人如蒿】形容杀的人多得数不清。同“杀人如麻”。 【杀人如芥】芥：小草。杀人像割草。形容杀人不当一回事。 【杀人如麻】如麻：象乱麻一样数不清。杀死的人多得象乱麻。形容杀的人多得数不清。 【视人如伤】把百姓当作有伤病的人一样照顾。旧时形容在位者关怀人民。同“视民如伤”。and more

Comment: I see. I've been mistaken all my life. It describes the unscrupulous attitude of the killer, not the numerousness of the killed.

Comment: @GeorgeChen, you are not wrong with your original thought. Refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 杀人如麻, 杀人： killing people; 如: 'like'; 麻(hemp): 乱麻(Baidu translates it as 'habijabi').

乱麻 is like this picture:

[image]

Can you count how many lines of 麻 in this picture??? If you can't, Can you imagine the same number of people were killed? That's what 杀人如麻 describes here.

Answer (score 2):

in literatures of yore, the term "殺人如*" has several variations.

in [陳拾遺集卷九](http://ctext.org/wiki.pl?if=en&chapter=200084)

> 殺人如麻﹒血流成澤

in [太白詩　白馬篇](http://ctext.org/wiki.pl?if=gb&chapter=75078)

> 殺人如剪草

in [建炎以來繫年要錄　卷四](http://ctext.org/wiki.pl?if=gb&chapter=246910)

> 殺人如刈麻﹒臭聞數百里

i would make a mental image of "殺人如麻" as "killing people like mowing hemps". such metaphor would be:

sickle - the sword, knife

mowing - killing (people) without considerations, massively

when mowing hemps, or grasses, no one spend time to examine particular grass, appreciate it's beauty; or consider the rationale of mowing.

hemps - life is worthless, without value

well, in mowing, one would consider cutting / clearing as many hemps / grasses as possible, with minimum efforts.